# How to use interface in swift with Kotlin multiplatform moblie

Tags: android, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I am trying to use interface in swift, but it unable to find the property

**commainMain**

```
interface ApplicationToken {
    val accessToken: String
    val refreshToken: String
}
```

**iosMain**

**Platform.kt**

```
lateinit var tokenProvider: ApplicationToken
```

**HttpClient.kt**

```
actual fun httpClient(config: HttpClientConfig<*>.() -> Unit) = HttpClient(Darwin) {
    config(this)
    engine {
        configureRequest {
            setAllowsCellularAccess(true)
        }
    }
    install(Auth) {
        bearer {
            loadTokens {
                BearerTokens(tokenProvider.accessToken, "")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I am to access **tokenProvider** in my swift code. It cannot find. I am adding image please have a look.

[image]

I tried another options to create class and implement my interface and call the class

```
class getToken : ApplicationToken {
  let accessToken: String = ""
  let refreshToken: String = ""
}

_ = getToken()
```

But it gives me the error. I cannot paste it because I don't understand in xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating code for extensions (e.g. `fun SomeClass.extension()`) and for global variables, like in your case, Kotlin creates kind of a namespace, related to the filename.

In your case your property should be under `PlatformKt.tokenProvider`.

---

Usually when it's hard to find how your kotlin code is visible on iOS side, it's useful to check out framework header file. It should be places somewhere around here(replace `shared` with your framework name):

```
shared/build/cocoapods/framework/shared.framework/Headers/shared.h
```

I prefer adding this file by reference in my Xcode project, so I can have fast access all the time:

[image]

Then you can easily search through this file for your variable/class/etc name.